# Highcharts Point.update() Crash On Google Chrome Version 49

Tags: google-chrome, crash, highcharts

Our company is currently using Highstock JS library in our trading platform’s charting module.

Previously, we never encountered such issue - but only recently we received complaints from our clients that our charting module crashed in Google Chrome.

We are also able to reproduce this issue from our side using Google Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 M.

After few days of investigation, it seems the problem is coming from Highcharts' Point.update() method.

We are able to reproduce this using the JSFiddle below. Please run this URL in your Chrome browser and wait for some time.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/RolandBanguiran/kfd52hfh][1]
```

By the way, we’ve tested using previous Chrome version with no problem.
Google Chrome 46.0.2490.80

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I run your example and wait couple minutes, indeed problem appears.

I reported that to our developers here:
- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5193